# Using Database.DeleteResult in custom code

Tags: apex, database

How can I use `Database.DeleteResult` for custom functionality.

I'd like to be able to construct it, set and get its fields.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context of the question a bit?  Is this for unit testing or returning Deleted Results to an external class?  Might be better to create a wrapper class of DeletedResults, and perhaps a constructor on the wrapper that takes in a DeleteResult parameter to populate the wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct almost any arbitrary type of data by using `JSON.deserialize(String, Type)`. The following example constructs a successful delete operation:

```
Database.DeleteResult dr = 
(Database.DeleteResult)JSON.deserialize('{"success": true, "id": "001000000000000"}', Database.DeleteResult.class);
```

You can also construct a failed operation using the same means; simply specify an array of errors to return. Note that if the errors array is passed, even if the array contains no values, success is automatically reverted to false.

You cannot modify the data inside of the Database.DeleteResult object itself, but you can choose to serialize it, modify the contents, then deserialize it. I suggest using "live" examples by actively deleting an item then debugging the results from JSON.serialize so you can get a sense of the proper JSON format.